Can't split string with regex
I want to split two sentences with 'apple' and 'apples' simultaneously. I try to use a regular expression 'apple*' or 'apple?'. But it doesn't work. I see the 's' in the second part of the second sentence. What's wrong with regex or split ?
$spl = '(apple*)'
'This apple for you','These apples for you' | % {$_ -split $spl}



If s is optional ?, then use $spl = '(apples?)'

Yeeeeeeeeeeeees!

$spl = 'apples?'
'This apple for you', 'This apples for you' | ForEach-Object { $_ -split $spl }



It turns out that I misunderstood how the regular expression works '?' )). ...previous character... Thanks!

Nice, though 'This apple for you', 'This apples for you' -split 'apples?' is more concise and performs better.

I'll add some explanation:
In regex * means "the character or sets of characters before it is repeated 0 or more times".
apple* would mean "e coming after appl is repeated 0 or more times", thus splitting at appl plus any number of e
Example:
$StringArray =  'This appl for you', 
                'This apple for you', 
                'This appleeee for you', 
                'This apples for you', 
                'This appleeees for you'


$StringArray | ForEach-Object { $_ -split '(apple*)' }

would result into
This 
appl
 for you


This
apple
 for you


This
appleeee
 for you


This
apple
s for you


This
appleeee
s for you

As other already answered what you need in this specific case is instead ?, which means "the character before it's repeated 0 or 1 times"  associated to the character s at the end of apple.
example:
$StringArray =  'This appl for you', 
                'This apple for you', 
                'This appleeee for you', 
                'This apples for you', 
                'This appleeees for you'


$StringArray | ForEach-Object { $_ -split '(apples?)' ; write-host "`n"}

would result into:
This appl for you


This
apple
for you


This
apple
eee for you


This
apples
for you


This
apple
eees for you


You can fix this simply by replacing the "*" with a "." at the end of apple.
This is what I ran:
$spl = '(apple.)'
'This apple for you','This apples for you' | % {$_ -split $spl}

This is because what you had "e*" would just check for any following "e". E.g. it would accept "appleeee" not any other character. Whereas "e." finds any character proceeding the "e" EXCEPT for newlines. E.g. "apples" "apple"
